# R studio: Error in vegdist(scale(env[, -i, drop = FALSE]), "euclid") : missing values are not allowed with argument 'na.rm = FALSE'

Tags: r

I'm doing a Mantel's test by using functions in `microeco` package (already done with other data without any problem), but when I send this code:

```
t1p$cal_mantel(use_measure = "bray", partial_mantel = TRUE)
```

it returns this error:

`Error in vegdist(scale(env[, -i, drop = FALSE]), "euclid") :  missing values are not allowed with argument 'na.rm = FALSE'`

I used the `is.na()` command to display null values, but there is no null data in my tables.
I think there is some problem in my input tables but I can't figure out what the problem is. Can someone help me please?

Comment: `microeco` is an interesting package. https://chiliubio.github.io/microeco_tutorial/other-examples-1.html#mantel-test-correlation-heatmap may help. Before the analysis, the data structure must be changed.

Comment: I used this  exact code (chiliubio.github.io/microeco_tutorial/…) for my previous Mantel figure and it worked perfectly. But with other data (formatted in the same way) it always gives me this error. Thanks

Comment: Could you check your data by using `str()` function. Is it exactly same with the example data in the package? And would you please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()`?. Info: Run `dput(head(your_dataset))`, then, copy & paste the output into your post.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was an hidden character in the table! I waited manually my table and...it worked!